# calculate how many times of the functions or variables be invoked

Tags: python

I want to get the invoked times of each function or variable from existing codes which is writing in python.

What i thought is override the object's **getattribute** function, such as below:

```
acc = {}

class object(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, p):
        acc.update({str(self) + p: acc.get(str(self) + p, 0) + 1})
        return supe(object, self).__getattribute__(p)

class A(object):
    def a(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def b(self):
        pass

def main():
    a = A()
    a.a()
    b = B()
    b.b()
    b.a = 'a'
    b.a

    print acc
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But, it only can calculate functions and variable in object, how can i calculate the normal functions or variable, such as:

```
def fun1():
    pass
fun1()
fun1()
```

I want to get the result as 2, is there any tool or method to do it?

I am sorry my pool english, What i really need is the invoked times not the run time.
such as above, we said, fun1() is invoked two times.

Comment: `class object(object)` - really?

Comment: yea, i think so, please forget my stupid method

Comment: How do you count variable invocations?

Comment: I only can count variable in object. When call a.a, it also call __getatrribute__

Answer (score 2):

Use a [decorator](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-decorator).

```
>>> def timestamp(container, get_timestamp):
...      def timestamp_decorator(func):
...          def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
...              container[func.func_name] = get_timestamp()
...              return func(*args, **kwargs)
...          return decorated
...      return timestamp_decorator
...
```

And you use it like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> def get_timestamp():
...     return datetime.datetime.now()
... 
>>> timestamps = {}
>>> @timestamp(timestamps, get_timestamp)
... def foo(a):
...     return a * 2
... 
>>> x = foo(2)
>>> print x, timestamps
4 {'foo': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 14, 9, 55, 15, 789893)}
```

Comment: Codes are alredy written, i don't want to add decorator to every function and how about variables?

Comment: @flreey, hmmm... will think about it.

Comment: i am sorry, my question mistake you, really i want to know how many times of a function is invoked. Such as, a = A(); a.fun(); a.f() and i want to get the result, a.fun has invoke two times;

Comment: also forgive my pool english, sorry

Answer (score 0):

There would be a way to create a counter decorator to a function (nbot a timestamp decorator) -and to automatically wrap all functions in a given module with this decorator -

so, if the module where you want to count the function calls in is named "mymodule" you can write:

```
class function_counter(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.counter = 0
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.counter += 1
        return self.func(*args, **kw)
```

And:

```
>>> @function_counter
... def bla():
...     pass
... 
>>> 
>>> bla()
>>> bla()
>>> bla()
>>> bla.counter
3
```

To apply this to all the functions in a module, you can write something like:

```
import mymodule
from types import FunctionType, BuiltinFunctionType
# define the "function_counter" class as above here (or import it)

for key, value in mymodule.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(value, (FunctionType, BuiltinFunctionType)):
        mymodule.__dict__[key] = function_counter(value)
```

That would do for counting function usage. 
If you want to count module level variable usage though, it is not that easy - as
you can't just override the mechanism attribute retrieving from a module object as you did for a class in your example.

The way to go there, is to substitute your module for a class - that implements the attribute counting scheme as you do in your example - after you import your module - and have all module attributes to be assigned to instance attributes in this class.

This is not a tested example (unlike the above), but try something along:

```
import mymodule

from types import FunctionType

class Counter(object):
   # counter __getattribute__ just as you did above

c = Counter()
for key, value in mymodule.__dict__.items():
    setattr(c, key, staticmethod(value) if isinstance(value, FunctionType) else value)
mymodule = c
```

Comment: I test your method, it only get the number of functions were defined when i import mymodule. And what i actually needed is something like can count ths invoked times of functions or variables while in runtime.